# How to register transaction including product prices in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, httpwebrequest, e-commerce

I'am trying to use Enhanced Ecommerce to track the e-commerce statistics of a webshop. We have some orders that are automatically triggered through a backend system. To measure these transactions we are using webrequests to send the data to Google Analytics.

This is based on some of the code provided by https://gist.github.com/0liver/11229128

I'm using the following parameters to register this transaction:

```
v=1                                   // Version.
&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y                       // Tracking ID / Property ID.
&cid=555                              // Anonymous Client ID.
&t=pageview                           // Pageview hit type.
&dh=mydemo.com                        // Document hostname.
&dp=/receipt                          // Page.
&dt=Receipt%20Page                    // Title.

&ti=T12345                            // Transaction ID. Required.
&ta=Google%20Store%20-%20Online       // Affiliation.
&tr=37.39                             // Revenue.
&tt=2.85                              // Tax.
&ts=5.34                              // Shipping.
&tcc=SUMMER2013                       // Transaction coupon.

&pa=purchase                          // Product action (purchase). Required.
&pr1id=P12345                         // Product 1 ID. Either ID or name must be set.
&pr1nm=Android%20Warhol%20T-Shirt     // Product 1 name. Either ID or name must be set.
&pr1ca=Apparel                        // Product 1 category.
&pr1br=Google                         // Product 1 brand.
&pr1va=Black                          // Product 1 variant.
&pr1ps=1                              // Product 1 position.
```

based on the information provided by https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide below the header Measuring Purchases.

All these values are coming in fine but I also want to register the product prices for each individual product in the transaction.

So according to Parameter Reference I can add it by using the Product Price parameter in combination with a product index.

> usage: `pr<productIndex>pr=29.20`

resulting in e.g. pr1pr=59.00

I made sure the prices are formatted correctly. Using only decimals and no comma's, but no price values are registering in Google Analytics.

Can the product prices be registered this way?
Should I use a different approach to fix this problem?

Comment: have you tried testing with https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/?

Comment: Yes, I copied the data post string containing all the parameters and values and copied that into the hit builder and validated it. It did not return any errors and I was able to send the hit.

Comment: and you waited 24 hours?

Comment: Yes, and the hit was registered along with the product information except for the product prices.

Comment: if you are 100 sure you sent it like you say make an example (get link or something) and post it an issue  link it back here I will ping someone on the team for you https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list

Comment: Let me see if I can set that up for you.

Comment: So I created a Console application that does a similar call to Google Analytics it is available for download [here](https://gterlouw@bitbucket.org/gterlouw/analyticsconsoleexample.git).

The repository also contains a executable to run the console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the data send by the console app is showing up in the Google Analytics Report. The way I build up the parameters seems to work just fine. Something else is going wrong in my application, irrelevant to Google Analytics. Thanks for your time DalmTo.